# reset userdefualts every time button is pressed (swift4)

Tags: ios, button, save, nsuserdefaults, swift4

I am trying to use userdefualts to save a tuple displayed on a label. Right now my code uses userdefulats as followed. If a, 2 then a, 3 is entered. The label displays a,2 a,2, a,3. The label is just appending each new entry. I need the userdefualt to overwrite whatever was just saved. So it should only display a,2 a,3.

```
        @IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
        if let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
        }

        llble.text = String(describing: result) + "\n"
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(llble.text, forKey: "name")

        }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let save : String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "name") as? String
        if let nameToDisplay = save {
            llble.text = nameToDisplay
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all values from the user defaults or remove just the value for the key "name"?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

```
if let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
}
```

Swift 3:

```
if let domain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(
domain)
}
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *domain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName: domain];
```

Calling this method is equivalent to initializing a user defaults object with `init(suiteName:)` passing domainName, and calling the `removeObject(forKey:)` method on each of its keys.

Also `synchronize()` is a legacy method and is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Do I put if let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
} in the button action or in viewdidappear? Thanks.

Comment: You should make a separate service/manager for this if you want to make it reuseble. If not - just make a method in your class smth like "func clearUserDefaults" and call it when button is tapped (cannot imagine why you should clear userdefaults in viewdidappear actually)

Comment: I just edited my code above buts its producing the same result its just appending the prior code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logic of result variable that is providing the string to the userdefault.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following approach in Swift. This would remove and delete all possible user defaults value.

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```